# Metallicity: What are the metallicity values of various galaxies?

Tags: galaxy

What are the various values of metallicity of various known galaxies, like Milky Way, Large Magellanic Cloud, Small Magellanic Cloud, Andromeda and so on?

Comment: You mean, local universe?

Comment: Ya, I mean the local group in this universe.

Comment: Do you need the exact values? And just out of curiosity: why?

Comment: yup. i think i need.Working on something. ;). Wikipedia says LMC is 40% of milky and SMC is 10% of milky.but a scientific paper assumes LMC's as 0.008 while for SMC as 0.004. Things that can't be connected.

Comment: post the wiki page please.

Comment: the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallicity,
the scientific paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1247

Comment: Can't grab it. Here is a catalog: http://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/SDSS/DR4/Data/stellarmet.html but is a bit of work.

Answer (score 3):

metallicity is a complicated issue, and giving just one number (usually Z, but also 12+log(O/H), ...) is very rough. But, here are the standard values for the Magellanic clouds:

LMC: Z~1/2

SMC: Z~1/5

with Z=1 being the solar value. Practically, the values will vary across any given galaxy (the Milky Way also has a metallicity gradient).

Reference:

Madden et al. 2014, PUBLICATIONS OF THE ASTRONOMICAL SOCIETY OF THE PACIFIC, 125:600–635, 2013 June
http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013PASP..125..600M

The article is also [available on astroPH](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2628)